# security in in-app-purchase iphone

Tags: iphone, security, ios4, in-app-purchase

I used in-app-purchase in my application. i am purchasing books from in-app-purchase. after successfully payment i am downloading books from my server. but i am thinking about the security. because if any user track the url of my server and download book and used without any payment. so can any one suggest how i enable security for this.

plz suggest
thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The in-app purchase transaction contains a receipt from Apple.  Apple also has a service that will verify that receipt.  So your iPhone app should pass the receipt to your server when requesting the download.  The server can then verify the receipt before sending the content.

See http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/VerifyingStoreReceipts/VerifyingStoreReceipts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH104-SW1

Comment: I am trying on test server (sandbox) and i tried approx 5-10 times and receipt is always approx same. so its not a problem?

Comment: Check the response you get back from Apple after verifying the receipt.  It contains a bunch of details about the transaction. Or just base64-decode the receipt and have a peek - though you're not supposed to look at the receipt directly in production because its format is subject to change.